# Selecting value return wrong value

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have Select in my View

Here is code

```
 <li class="airline">
      <select name="search[airline]" id="search_airline" class="custom" style="display: none;">
          <option value="">Alla</option>
          <option value="SK">SAS</option>
          <option value="DY">Norwegian</option>
          <option value="EI">Aer Lingus</option>
          <option value="SU">Aeroflot</option>
          <option value="AR">Aerolineas Argentinas</option>
          <option value="AM">Aeromexico</option>
          <option value="BT">Air Baltic</option>
          <option value="AC">Air Canada</option>
          <option value="CA">Air China</option>
          <option value="UX">Air Europa</option>
          <option value="AF">Air France</option>
          <option value="AI">Air India</option>
          <option value="NZ">Air New Zealand</option>
          <option value="AZ">Alitalia</option>
          <option value="NH">All Nippon Airways</option>
          <option value="AA">American Airlines</option>
          <option value="OS">Austrian Airlines</option>
          <option value="VO">Austrian Arrows</option>
          <option value="BA">British Airways</option>
          <option value="BD">British Midland</option>
          <option value="SN">Brussels Airlines</option>
          <option value="CX">Cathay Pacific</option>
          <option value="CO">Continental Airlines</option>
          <option value="OK">Czech Airlines</option>
          <option value="DL">Delta Airlines</option>
          <option value="EK">Emirates</option>
          <option value="EY">Etihad Airways</option>
          <option value="AY">Finnair</option>
          <option value="GA">Garuda Indonesia</option>
          <option value="IB">Iberia</option>
          <option value="FI">Icelandair</option>
          <option value="KL">KLM</option>
          <option value="KE">Korean Air Lines</option>
          <option value="LA">LAN Airlines</option>
          <option value="LO">LOT - Polish Airlines</option>
          <option value="NG">Lauda Air</option>
          <option value="LH">Lufthansa</option>
          <option value="DM">Maersk Air</option>
          <option value="MH">Malaysian Airlines</option>
          <option value="TF">Malmö Aviation</option>
          <option value="MX">Mexicana Airlines</option>
          <option value="NW">Northwest Airlines</option>
          <option value="DY">Norwegian</option>
          <option value="OA">Olympic Airways</option>
          <option value="QF">Qantas Airways</option>
          <option value="QR">Qatar Airways</option>
          <option value="SK">SAS</option>
          <option value="SQ">Singapore Airlines</option>
          <option value="SA">South African Airways</option>
          <option value="LX">Swiss Intl Air Lines</option>
          <option value="TP">TAP Portugal</option>
          <option value="TG">Thai Airways</option>
          <option value="TK">Turkish Airlines</option>
          <option value="UA">United Airlines</option>
          <option value="VS">Virgin Atlantic Airw.</option>
          <option value="VY">Vueling</option>
          <option value="WF">Wideroe</option>
      </select>
      <span tabindex="0" id="search_airline-button" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="search_airline-menu" aria-haspopup="true" class="ui-selectmenu-button ui-selectmenu-button-closed ui-corner-all ui-button ui-widget"><span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
          <span class="ui-selectmenu-text">Flygbolag: Alla</span>
      </span>
 </li>
```

Also I have function in TS that make variable in it with word - "Flygbolag"

Here is it

```
function update_search_airline() {
    $(".ui-selectmenu-text", $("#search_airline-button")).html(
  __("Flygbolag") + ": " + $(".ui-selectmenu-text", $("#search_airline-button")).html());
}
```

So when I load page all okay and I get for example

[image]

But when I select value from this select I need to make it with this word too

So in function I make this code

```
function load_field_actions(): void {
  $(".tooltip").tooltipster()
  $("#search_airline").change(update_search_airline)
}
```

And this row must update it correctly

> $("#search_airline").change(update_search_airline)

But it just change default value to next value without Flygbolag

Comment: Please, add just the minimal code needed to reproduce the issue. Also try to include the code in a snippet, so we can reproduce the error.

Comment: I edited post @CalvinNunes

Comment: If its a literal just put `.html("Flygbolag": " + [...]`